# How to learn from what search engine and with which query a user found my site?

Tags: php, search-engine

I would like to know which search engine and what particular query led a user to my site. I have partially solved this problem. I can determine from what search engine the user has logged in to the site. But I am not able to find out what query has been used.

This is what I have so far:

```
$R=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
echo "<br />this 1^".$R;

$A=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$U=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$R=urldecode ($R);    

echo "this  IP - ".$A."<br>";
echo "this  - ".$U."<br>";
if (strpos($S, "yandex") != 0) {
  preg_match('"text=(.*?)[^&]*"', $S, $arr);
  echo "this  ".$arr[1];
}
elseif (strpos($S, "google") != 0) {
  preg_match('/q=(.*)&/sei', $S, $arr);
  echo "this  Google ".$arr[1];
}
elseif (strpos($S, "rambler") != 0) {
  preg_match('"query=(.*?)[^&]*"', $S, $arr);
  echo "this  Rambler  ".$arr[1];
}
else {
  echo "this  ".$R;
}
echo "<br />this ^^".$R;
echo "<br />this  ^^".$R;
```

All `$_SERVER ['HTTP_REFERER']` appears to be encoded like this:

```
this  ^^http://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fxn--80aag0ab4aqcid.xn--p1ai%2F&ei=YuDxU6L3PKPMyAO-3ID4Aw&usg=AFQjCNHUtFnVLIHqgsuC9skqk8Qje9K3Bg&sig2=12UXCtusUAr5pvAQGxb_Hg
```

How can I find out what search query led the user to my site?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. I've voted to reopen the question. Please take a __[tour]__ and see if there is any way you can further improve the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can't get the search query when the search comes from Google**. Other search providers will still provide keyword data (at the moment).

The reason is because Google has now moved to Secure Search (encrypted searches using HTTPS). See [Goodbye, Keyword Data: Google Moves Entirely to Secure Search](http://searchenginewatch.com/article/2296351/Goodbye-Keyword-Data-Google-Moves-Entirely-to-Secure-Search) for more information:

> Nearly two years after making one of the biggest changes to secure search that resulted in a steady rise in "(not provided)" data, Google has switched all searches over to encrypted searches using HTTPS. This means no more keyword data will be passed to site owners.
>
> **Encrypted Google searches don't pass the keyword data through to websites, thereby eliminating the ability to track users by their keyword searches.**

...

> At this point, it seems even when you aren't logged in, using private browsing (or incognito mode) and forcibly type , you are being redirected to the HTTPS version, thereby encrypting your search and no doubt leading to a total removal of keyword data – at least from Google search visitors. Remember, keyword data from other search engines – like Bing, for example – still send keyword data through.

See also [How to get the referer search query from google?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12181375/how-to-get-the-referer-search-query-from-google?rq=1)